# Request Applescript to copy only one file type from 2 folders, into a 3rd folder

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, catalina

Hi I've been trying to find utilities that will do this but I am guessing applescript/Automator on Catalina mac would work too.

Basically I have 2 folders with all kinds of books (.pdf, .mobi and .epub) and subfolders too. I want to only copy files of extension epub type in these 2 folders, into a 3rd folder.

So by running the script the third folder would have only unique EPUB files from the former two folders.

Can anyone please advise me how to write this up in Automator? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run this in Terminal you can use

```
find /path/to/top/of/source -type f -iname '*.epub' -exec cp '{}' /path/to/target/ \;
```

This will duplicate all files, which might be heavy on disk space depending on the number and size of your Epubs. You can also just link them by using

```
find /path/to/top/of/source -type f -iname '*.epub' -exec ln '{}' /path/to/target/ \;
```

Comment: Thanks the first cmd will traverse thru subfolders too?

Comment: @sd100 `find` always does by default. You can run `find /path/to/top/of/source -type f -iname '*.epub' -print` first to see which files it finds.

Comment: Yes the find command worked great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are actually many different ways to do it in **Automator**! Here is one set of *actions* you could use:

- **Ask For Finder Items**
- **Get Folder Contents**
- **Filter Finder Items**
- **Copy Finder Items**

Comment: Thanks would this copy within subfolders also or i need to add recursive option in the cp command?

Comment: @sd100, Sorry, I missed the subfolder part in your OP, use the Automator workflow instead.

Comment: @sd100, You could use this _compound command_ in **Terminal** to do it: `while IFS= read -r f; do cp -n "$f" "/path/to/destination/"; done < <(find /path/to/source -type f -iname '*.epub' 2>/dev/null)`